# skipping incompatible ../tracker/libdeepsort.so when searching for -ldeepsort

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, arm64

I tried to create a shared library (.so file) for aarch64 device with CMake, however, cmake compiling the scripts with the type of x86-64. What I need is ARM aarch64 format. If anybody knows please help me?

my cmake file :

```
PROJECT(deepsort)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)

AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(./errmsg DIR_SRCS_errmsg)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(./thirdPart DIR_SRCS_hungarianoper)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(./thirdPart/munkres DIR_SRCS_munkres)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(./thirdPart/munkres/adapters DIR_SRCS_munkres_adapters)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(./matching DIR_SRCS_matching)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(./feature DIR_SRCS_feature)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(./common DIR_SRCS_common)
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(./api DIR_SRCS_api)

include_directories(
./errmsg
./thirdPart
./thirdPart/Eigen
./thirdPart/munkres
./thirdPart/munkres/adapters
./matching
./feature
./common
./api
)

add_library(deepsort SHARED 
${DIR_SRCS_errmsg} 
${DIR_SRCS_hungarianoper} 
${DIR_SRCS_munkres} 
${DIR_SRCS_munkres_adapters} 
${DIR_SRCS_feature} 
${DIR_SRCS_matching} 
${DIR_SRCS_api}
)

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)  
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)  
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)  
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)  
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")  
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)  
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")  
else()  
     message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")  
endif()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by putting cxx and c variables in Cmakelists.txt file:

```
set(tools /usr/bin)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)
```

if you want to compile in a different environment then you would have to download chain tools.